# How rewrite POST method on rest akka-http

Tags: java, spring-mvc, akka-http

I try to rewrite POST method from Spring to akka-http. To write akka-http minimal application I used tutorial - [akka-http-quickstart-java](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-http-quickstart-java/). It has next routing:

```
post(() ->
    entity(
        Jackson.unmarshaller(User.class),
        user ->
            onSuccess(createUser(user), performed -> {
              log.info("Create result: {}", performed.description);
              return complete(StatusCodes.CREATED, performed, Jackson.marshaller());
            })
    )
),
```

Could you please help me add request, response to this routing, handling content `TwimlMessageRequest` and response with content type `"application/xml"`   like in POST method in Spring API

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
void GetMessage(@ModelAttribute TwimlMessageRequest twimlMessageRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) throws IOException{
....
        response.setContentType("application/xml");

        response.getWriter().print(twimlResponse.toXml());
```